# Swift Change the tableviewcell border color according to data

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift3, custom-cell

I have written a code for making the cell border color change according to inStock or outStock , if it is inStock it will be red border else it would be green, but I it is not working for me, I put it in willDisplayCell and here is my code :

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                   willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell,
                   forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear


        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

        let whiteRoundedView : UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:10,y: 5,width: self.view.frame.size.width - 20,height: 214))





    whiteRoundedView.layer.masksToBounds = false
    whiteRoundedView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
    whiteRoundedView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: -1,height: 1)
 whiteRoundedView.layer.borderWidth = 2


    cell.contentView.addSubview(whiteRoundedView)
    cell.contentView.sendSubview(toBack: whiteRoundedView)



    if stock[indexPath.row] == "inStock" {

        whiteRoundedView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    }
    else {   
    whiteRoundedView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.green.cgColor

    }



}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try to move your code into `cellForRowAt` method like that

```
cell.layer.masksToBounds = true
cell.layer.cornerRadius = 5
cell.layer.borderWidth = 2
cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: -1, height: 1)
let borderColor: UIColor = (stock[indexPath.row] == "inStock") ? .red : .green
cell.layer.borderColor = borderColor.cgColor
```

Comment: thanks it works fine, but the problem is that the border is sticking to the edge of table I need it smaller edge

Answer (score 0):

You are adding your whiteRoundedView multiple time for each cell - as cell instances are reused.

You should only create this once (when creating UITableViewCell) - and then manipulate color of it after that in willDisplayCell function.

I would suggest creating custom UITableViewCell, but you can also avoid that problem by using view "tag" property and checking if it exists already.