# UITableViewCell how to add solid border with rounded corners

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift4

I want to add a table with a solid border with rounded corners:
[image: table with each cell having a solid border and rounded corners].

I have tried using a CALayer, which can be called making the cell and adds rounded corners:

```
  let maskLayer = CALayer()
  maskLayer.cornerRadius = 10   //if you want round edges
  maskLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
  maskLayer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
  maskLayer.borderWidth = 5
  self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor // no change
  self.layer.borderWidth = 5 // no change
  maskLayer.frame = CGRect(x: self.bounds.origin.x, y: self.bounds.origin.y, width: self.bounds.width, height: self.bounds.height).insetBy(dx: horizontalPadding/2, dy: verticalPadding/2)
  self.layer.mask = maskLayer
```

I have tried adding borders, but the rounded corners look very messy. How would I add rounded corners and a solid border?

I have looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44663217/swift-change-the-tableviewcell-border-color-according-to-data) which talks about changing border colours, but it does not give the cells a rounded border like in the image above. Only the top and bottom have a rounded border.

Comment: Try `self.layer.addSublayer(maskLayer)`

Comment: That definitely does something. If I also remove the self.layer.border, then I get single rounded solid border. The only issue is the cell content vanishes and now I only have the border

Comment: Are you doing this on cell view or cell content view ?

Comment: I've made a custom cell and I'm calling it from the layoutsubviews method, so cell view

Comment: Then try `self.layer.insertSublayer(maskLayer below: self.layer)`

Comment: self.layer.insertSublayer(maskLayer, below: self.layer) has the same issue

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swift Change the tableviewcell border color according to data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44663217/swift-change-the-tableviewcell-border-color-according-to-data)

Comment: @Teja I've tried the above on the content view and that did not work.

Comment: @Koen I will take a look at that now

Comment: I changed  maskLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor to  maskLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor and the above worked. Thanks Teja and Koen. Feel free to post it as an answer and I will accept.

Comment: You can answer your own question with the updated code. You figured it out yourself, so no need for others to get the credit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how to do it with CALayer(). I Always make a cell with 2 UIViews. 1 "background view" behind the other. This will also create a border. This will have the same result as far as I'm aware. Could this be what you're looking for?

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

var viewBackground = UIView()
var viewBackgroundBorder = UIView()

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        backgroundColor = .clear
        viewBackground.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        viewBackgroundBorder.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        viewBackgroundBorder.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        viewBackground.layer.cornerRadius = 9 

        addSubview(viewBackgroundBorder)
        addSubview(viewBackground)

        viewBackgroundBorder.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        viewBackground.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        let constraints = [
            viewBackgroundBorder.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 0),
            viewBackgroundBorder.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 0),
            viewBackgroundBorder.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: 0),
            viewBackgroundBorder.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: 0),

            viewBackground.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 2),
            viewBackground.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 2),
            viewBackground.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -2),
            viewBackground.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -2)]

            NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints) 
    }

   required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, interesting solution. I have managed to get it working with a CALayer now (see comments).

Comment: @trees_are_great Cool! yeah, I saw some solutions. Didn't know you could do it like that too... Interesting

Comment: The issue with the CALayer, is I'm struggling to get the cell colour to be different from the background layer, so that light grey background is showing as white. I might give your solution a go after all.

Comment: With this answer, it's possible to get a different colour for the cell inside the border as to outside the border. However, the outline isn't as smooth as it is with a CALayer. For my case, that means I would prefer the CALayer solution

Comment: Actually, when I make the border 1px thick and round it by 5 and 4, it looks alright to me

Comment: Note also, for me it needed to be called from awakeFromNib rather than ngOnIt. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/38966583/2945345

Comment: Nice. Okay, awakeFromNib can also be a case. Is CALayer more smooth? Huh, okay. Maybe I will look into this as well. Good to hear this at least worked for you.

Comment: Wait, it makes sense CALayer is more smooth. At the moment you have to make 2 views have rounded corners and they have to match each other perfectly, which is indeed hard to do...

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind each cell being in a new section, then it is possible like this:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 3
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
         return 15
     }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 100 ;
    }
```

Then in your `cellForRowAt` method, get the sectionIndex with indexPath.section. You can then add the corner radius and border to the cell itself by clicking on the cell and using the attributes inspector.

Option 2 - not using a new section for each cell
The following code can be called from the custom cell's awakeFromNib method.

```
  let maskLayer = CALayer()
  maskLayer.cornerRadius = 10  
  maskLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
  maskLayer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
  maskLayer.borderWidth = 5
  maskLayer.frame = CGRect(x: self.bounds.origin.x, y: self.bounds.origin.y, width: self.bounds.width, height: self.bounds.height).insetBy(dx: horizontalPadding/2, dy: verticalPadding/2)
  self.layer.insertSublayer(maskLayer, below: self.layer)
```

The limitation of this answer is that you can't get the cell background to be a different color from the table background (well, at least I couldn't). It does have smoother rounded corners than that of [MuSoundiX's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62044806/2945345).

Comment: Actually, have you tried the border settings directly on the main layer, so skip the maskLayer? So, `layer.cornerRadius = 10`, etc.

Comment: Yes, it would give a corner radius on the top and bottom cell, but the cells in-between were together and did not have rounded corners.